# When should we use split() in Python?

Tags: python

So I would like to remove the white space from my integer input and store them into a list.

```
t = raw_input().split()
numbers = [int(x.strip()) for x in t]
numbers = sorted(numbers)
print numbers
```

However, the output's still the same when I don't use `strip()`. Can somebody please explain to me why we should use `strip()`. I saw a couple of posts on the forum and people also frequently use `strip()`. I understand `split()` returns all the numbers by eliminating the white space, and `strip()` also does the same job.

Thanks!

Comment: [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) vs [`str.strip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip)

Comment: input: `' 1 2 3 '`, `split: `['1','2','3'], strip: `'1 2 3'`

Comment: How did the documentation of [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) and [`strip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) make you think that those functions do the same thing?

Comment: FWIW, `int()` ignores leading & trailing whitespace on a string argument, so you never need to do call `strip` on strings you pass to `int()`. OTOH, `.split()` removes _all_ whitespace so it's pointless calling `.strip()` on the strings in the list it returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand the confusion. The `split()` function return a list of all subparts of your string by removing all occurences of the given argument.

For example, if you have the following string : "Hello world!" and split this one by split("o") then your output will be : ["Hell", " w", "rld!"]

With a code:

```
str = "Hello world!"
split_str = str.split("o")

print "str has type", type(str), "with the value", str, "\n"
print "split_str has type", type(split_str), "with the value", split_str
```

Then, the output will be :

> str has type string with the value Hello world!
>
> split_str has type list with the value ["Hell", " w", "rld!"]

So, if you have a string that represents a sequence of different integers separated by space: you could operate with this solution.

```
input_integers = raw_input().split(" ") # splits the given input string
numbers = [int(x) for x in input_integers] # iteration to convert from string to int
numbers = sorted(numbers) # makes a sort on the integer list
print numbers # display
```

It's a very basic use of string so, for the next time, have the reflex to read the doc. It's the first tool that you may read to have your solution.

Answer (score 0):

`split(split_item)` returns a list with dividing the input by the split_item

`strip(strip_item)` will remove the strip_item from leading and trailing end and will return the remaining item.

eg:

`a = " how are you "`

`a.split()` will give `['how', 'are', 'you']`

`a.strip()` will give `'how are you'`

You can specify any string inside the `()`

`a.split("o")` will give `[' h', 'w are y', 'u ']`

`a.strip("o")` will give `' how are you '` --> same string